# How to run electron project

Tags: electron, atom-editor

Today I have just started to learn Electron.

I don't understand more about it but I think:

- Electron is a language like C#.
- Atom is a Text Editor like notepad++.

Inside Atom.io I have created a Folder called Demo which has 3 files as follows:

```
Demo
  |--package.json
  |--main.js
  |--index.html
```

In package.json:

```
{
  "name"    : "Demo",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "main"    : "main.js"
}
```

In main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');

const {app} = electron;

const {BrowserWindow} = electron;

let win;

function createWindow() {

  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

In index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to know that how can I run this project? Do I need to install anything else to run it?

I am using Windows 8.1

Comment: Electron is written in node.js, install node.js and you're done

Comment: @MassimilianoArione How do I install node.js??

Comment: Download it from official website https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: @MassimilianoArione I have installed Node.js from the link you suggested. Now how can I run my project??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to download and install node.js from its [official website](https://nodejs.org/en/) as @Massimilliano Arione suggested in the question comments.

Then I run Command Prompt or CMD and run this command:

```
npm install electron
```

That downloaded electron as a winrar archieve named electron-v1.2.2-win32-x64 to C:\Users\Vishal.electron

Then I extracted it to D:\Electron

Then in Command Prompt I ran these commands:

```
D:
cd Electron
electron G:\Work\Electron\Demo
```

where G:\Work\Electron\Demo is the path of my Project.

That's it. Now it runs.

Answer (score 9):

**Electron** is not a language. It's a framework to build cross-platform desktop applications with web technologies (HTML, CSS, JS) built with NodeJS.

So when to build app with Electron, you have both [ElectronAPI](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/) and [npm ecosystem](https://www.npmjs.com/) at your disposal.

To run your **Electron** app, you can follow:

- [Run your app - Quick Start guide](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/#run-your-app)

and/or clone [electron-quick-start repo](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start).